# How to create a dual page iOS app

Tags: ios, swift

How do I create a dual page `iOS` app?
I want to toggle between pages through a `UIPageViewController`. When I selected "page based app" it provides me `RootViewController` and `DataViewController` and I got confused.

Please help? Also, what is modelcontroller.swift?

Comment: The `ModelController` is where the page content is defined.

Answer (score 2):

You can create the Dual page view controller by starting from single view controller app. Once done embed it in navigation controller or in tabbed view controller and create segue accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want your page to look.  For example to set the page titles in the default page-based app, change the lines in ModelController.swift

```
// Create the data model.
var dateFormatter: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
self.pageData = dateFormatter.monthSymbols().copy()
```

to

```
// Create the data model.
self.pageData = ["Title A", "Title I", "Page 1"]    // Your pages
```

Comment: I got what I wanted by tabbed view app.